# How to get User's table from Firebase events in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am trying to look at old events based on user's current values. Events from Firebase Analytics are exported in single table together with User data(user data is part of event record).
How can I join old event to current user? Is it possible to export User table separately?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can identify a user with either user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id or user_dim.user_id.  You can read more about these fields in this [help center article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512).

Comment: For me, "resettable_device_id" is null

Comment: @Sharpless512 remember check the "Include Advertising Identifiers in BigQuery export" option when link your project, like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObRfo.png , if you already linked, unlink project then link again, you will get the id in your BigQuery.

Comment: @DennyHuang ok thanks, I will do that now. And see if it helps